# Xamarin forms: Search arrow is not available on ios soft keyboard

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, return-type

I have added the following properties to `Entry` for send option in the soft keyboard.

```
ReturnType="Send"
ReturnCommand="{Binding SendFromKeyboard}"
```

On Android, the `send` arrow is showing on the keyboard. But on ios, no `Send` arrow is available on the keyboard. But if the `ReturnType` is `Search` the search option is available for both android and ios. Is there any additional settings for `send` option in ios keyboard?

**Complete Xaml Code:**

```
<Frame 
     Padding="8,0,8,0"
     Margin="10,5,0,10"
     BackgroundColor="White"
     HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
     VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
     CornerRadius="10">

     <Entry 
        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        x:Name="amount_entry"
        PlaceholderColor="#c3c3c3"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
        HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
        BackgroundColor="White"
        FontFamily="Bold"
        ReturnType="Send"
        ReturnCommand="{Binding AddPointsFromKeyboard}"
        Keyboard="Numeric"
        TextColor="#464646"
        TextChanged="Calculate_Points"
        Placeholder="Enter Amount">
     </Entry>
</Frame>
```

**Update for @MatthewLC**

In PCL:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class PointsEntry : Entry
    {
    }
}
```

In IOS:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Business_App.iOS;
using Business_App.Renderer;
using CoreGraphics;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(PointsEntry), typeof(PointsEntryRenderer))]
namespace Business_App.iOS
{
    public class PointsEntryRenderer : EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null && this.Element.Keyboard == Keyboard.Numeric)
            {
                this.AddDoneButton();
            }
        }

        protected void AddDoneButton()
        {
            var toolbar = new UIToolbar(new CGRect(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, 44.0f));

            var doneButton = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, delegate
            {
                this.Control.ResignFirstResponder();
                var baseEntry = this.Element.GetType();
                ((IEntryController)Element).SendCompleted();
            });

            toolbar.Items = new UIBarButtonItem[] {
                new UIBarButtonItem (UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace),
                doneButton
            };
            this.Control.InputAccessoryView = toolbar;
         }
    }
 }
```

On XAML:

```
<local2:PointsEntry 
    HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    x:Name="amount_entry"
    PlaceholderColor="#c3c3c3"
    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
    BackgroundColor="White"
    FontFamily="Bold"
    ReturnType="Send"
    ReturnCommand="{Binding AddPointsFromKeyboard}"
    Keyboard="Numeric"
    TextColor="#464646"
    TextChanged="Calculate_Points"
    Placeholder="Enter Amount">
 </local2:PointsEntry>
```

After adding the `customrenderer` also there is no send text on the soft keyboard. If I remove the `keyboard` property, then send text is showing on the soft keyboard. I am looking for both numeric keyboard and send text on soft keyboard together.

Comment: Is the "Send" *text* shown on iOS?

Comment: @Vahid No, clear option is showing instead

Comment: I tested `ReturnType="Send"`, on Android it shows a send arrow icon, and on iOS it shows just _Send_ text. And it's a normal behavior.

Comment: @Vahid But for me, there is no send test. I have added my complete entry code to the question.

Comment: I figured out that the problem is caused by **Keyboard** property. If you set Keyboard as one of _Numeric_ or _Telephone_ the ReturnType will be set to _Clear_. I don't know if it's the normal behavior of iOS or it's a bug.

Comment: Delete the folder bin and obj in iOS project  ,then rebuild your project .

Comment: It's strange because I used exactly your code and removed Keyboard property, and the "Send" text appeared.

Comment: @Vahid You are right, the problem is with the numeric keyboard. Something happens wrong when I remove the keyboard property from my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Custom Renderer**

```
using App1.iOS;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(Entry),typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class MyEntryRenderer:EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if(Control!=null)
            {
                Control.ReturnKeyType = UIReturnKeyType.Send;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

## Update

Because you set the keyboard type as Numeric .So in iOS it will never show the `Send`button .

If you do want to input number , you can check if the value is a number in command .

Comment: Because you set the keyboard type as `Numeric` .So in iOS it will never show the return Button .

Comment: you are right, if i remove the keyboard property I can see the send text on soft keyboard. Please update the answer.

Comment: If you do want to input number , you can check if the value is a number in command .

Comment: Please update the answer with the keyboard property issue, i will accept

Comment: Is there any way to show numeric keyboard and sent text together?

Comment: You can use some third party keyboard ,which I don't suggest you to do it .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197566/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-sreejith-sree).

Answer (score 0):

If helps anyone. Based on others answers i was able to do a custom render that inherit from entry as follow:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null && this.Element.Keyboard == Keyboard.Numeric)
            {

                this.AddDoneButton();
            }
        }

        protected void AddDoneButton()
        {

            var toolbar = new UIToolbar(new CGRect(0.0f, 0.0f, 50.0f, 44.0f));

            var doneButton = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done, delegate
            {
                this.Control.ResignFirstResponder();
                var baseEntry = this.Element.GetType();
                ((IEntryController)Element).SendCompleted();
            });

            toolbar.Items = new UIBarButtonItem[] {
                new UIBarButtonItem (UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace),
                doneButton
            };
            this.Control.InputAccessoryView = toolbar;


        }
```

Comment: Is this a solution to showing numeric keyboard and sent text together?

Comment: Yes. I use normal entries with text and numeric type and use the completed event. In iOS that is no button that shows with numeric keyboard, so i do these custom render for entry only for iOS.

Comment: I have updated the question with your suggestions, can you please have a look?

Comment: All right, but if you need this to work in every entry you can just add the entry in the custom render instead of PointsEntry. That way you don't need to do nothing on forms side.